# Three different ways of finding $P(X<Y<Z)$

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions

Let $X,Y,Z \sim N(0,1)$ be i.i.d. Find $P(X<Y<Z)$.

I can think of solving this problem in three different ways but got stuck on two:

**Method 1 (use symmetry):**

As $X,Y,Z$ are i.i.d, they can by symmetry can any position with equal probability in the three positions, $\_<\_<\_$ of this inequality. Thus, there are $3!$ possibilities and one favorable outcome, leading to the solution $P(X<Y<Z)=1/3!=1/6$.

**Method 2 (decompose the three-long inequality to two-long inequality and then use symmetry )**

If only realized the symmetry $P(X<Y)$ and $P(Y<Z)$ for two random variables at a time but not the three, then one would decompose the three-long into two-long and then apply symmetry.

$P(X<Y<Z)= P(X<Y,Y<Z)=P(X<Y)P(Y<Z)=1/2 \cdot 1/2 =1/4$

The first inequality is rewriting the three-long-inequality event into the identifical event "$X<Y,Y<Z$". The second equality uses independence. The third equality relies on symmetry again (one favorable event out of two possible).

But  the 1/4 solution is different from the method 1 solution of 1/6. I suspect that independence does not hold for the event "$X<Y,Y<Z$" but have not managed to convince myself fully why these are dependent. If they are dependent, how would you go about solving this problem through method 2?

**Method 3 (use integrals)**

If one did not see the symmetry in method 1 or 2, then one would likely use a direct method (integration) for calculating this probability.

$$
\begin{align}
P(X<Y<Z)=\int_{X \cdot Y \cdot Z}I(x<y<z)f(x,y,z)dxdydz
\end{align}
$$

We are integrating over the joint support of all three variables $\int_{X \cdot Y \cdot Z}$. The indicator variable $I(x<y<z)$ ensures that we are integrating over the joint space of interest and $f(x,y,z)$ is the joint density. As I am mainly used to integration in one dimension, I am not sure how I can evaluate this integral and show that it amounts to $1/6$ -- perhaps using some R code for convenience.

Your guidance is appreciated.

Comment: The event of $X<Y$ is evidence that $Y$ is large.  Likewise, $Y<Z$ is evidence that $Y$ is small.  These events cannot be independent - they are both contingent on the value of $Y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Methof 2 is wrong: $X<Y$ and $Y<Z$ are not independent.
Methof 3 is too complicated if you try to integrate w.r.t one variable at a time. Using symmetry in $x,y,z$  is the the best way. $\frac  1 6$ is the right answer.

Comment: Thanks, yes I see now how method 2 is wrong and agree that method 1 is the best way. I wonder however if you could give a pointer to how you would start and roughly carry out method 3?

Comment: @Adel Method 3 is not recommended. Unless you bring in symmetry again your calculations get too hard.